# How to automatically determine customer industry from email address or company name?

Tags: web-scraping

I have a customer database containing email addresses and company names. I want to know what industries my customers are in so that I can analyze revenue statistics. However, I have historically not asked my customers what industries they are in. And when a customer signs up for my web app, I want to ask them as few questions as possible, so I'd rather not ask them for their industry if I can avoid it.

I know that industry information is sort-of public. I can manually scrape them from LinkedIn. There may be other sites too where I can lookup industry information too. But the LinkedIn ToS does not allow automatic scraping. So I'm wondering whether there are other automatic ways to determine a customer's industry, based on either an email address or a company name.